# backbone library code patterns I couldn't understand

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am intermediate level javascript developer trying to understand how great javascript developer write their code and i decide to start looking into Backbone library as starting point.

here is some code snippet for initial setup in backbone please help me to make sense out of it.

**code1** -

```
(function(){
   var root = this;
}).call(this);
```

is there any specific reason to use call method over simply using (), or it is just a coding preference, if i have to write the same code i would do something like this.

```
(function(root){

})(this);
```

**code2** -

```
  var Backbone;
  if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    Backbone = exports;
  } else {
    Backbone = root.Backbone = {};
  }
```

now there is no definition of export in the global scope nor it is defined anywhere in local scope then what is if block is doing here if i was writing the same code i would write

```
  var Backbone = root.Backbone = {};
```

**code 3**

```
var _ = root._;
if (!_ && (typeof require !== 'undefined')) _ = require('underscore')._;
```

again I can't find definition of require anywhere in local or global scope

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Code Block 1

This is down to developer preference, you could write that code either way and, indeed, many libraries do prefer your suggested style.

#### Code Block 2

This block is a take on the [AMD Boiler Plate](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2010/09/30/run-anywhere-javascript-modules-boilerplate-code/).  AMD libraries provide the hooks required to [split your JavaScript code into modules](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/).  In the code blocks case, the `exports` object is a global used by the [CommonJS Module Standard](http://dailyjs.com/2010/10/18/modules/).  If the `exports` global is not present then Backbone is added to the `root` object directly.

An interesting side note on this is the fact that Backbone does not support exporting to the popular [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) AMD library.

#### Code Block 3

`require` is another global introduced by AMD libraries, see above.

Answer (score 2):

In **code1** `call(this)` passes a reference of the current `this` to the function. In case of doing it in the global scope, `this` is `window`. I think it's just preference and doesn't make a difference in that case.

`require` and `exports` are provided by NodeJS (or CommonJS compliant library) and they're part of the CommonJS spec.

Comment: can you explain a little more about purpose behind exports and require and why they are global instead of under some namespace like Node.exports

Comment: Yes, because it's not just NodeJS that provides this, any library that is compliant with CommonJS modules spec makes use of it, such as [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) for browsers which also supports AMD modules.

Answer (score 0):

I think that code 2 is to protect the framework in case someone else defined exports in global scope. So they check if its not undefined meaning someone else did then they just reset it to an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

@JonnyReeves has pretty much answered all of your questions. Not sure you've seen the annotated source code of backbone.js before, this would be useful for you.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html